# Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support

Tags: server-setup, captcha, centos, linux, magento2.2.0

After entering my username and password into the admin uri of magento I get the following error in `system.log`

```
[2017-10-09 00:00:00] main.CRITICAL: Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support [] []
```

there is no such requirement listed by the [magento installation guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Is there a php module I have to enable/install?  `php -m|grep -i -e 'font'` lists nothing...  `freetype` and `freetype-devel` (v2.4.11)have both been installed to the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to change the php configure script to include `--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib64/` where `/usr/lib64` contains the `libfreetype.so` file.

My final configuration so far looks like:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs --enable-bcmath --with-curl --with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64/ --with-png-dir=/usr/lib64/ --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib64/ \
--enable-intl --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-openssl \
--with-pdo-mysql --enable-soap --with-xsl --enable-zip --enable-opcache  --with-config-file-path=/etc
```

then you need to `make;make install;` and restart the web server.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14, I needed to first install libfreetype-dev: 
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev, and then my config directive was: 
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'

Comment: @user3338098 Please consider accepting your own answer as the accepted answer to this question. It also worked for me thank you.

Answer (score 7):

For docker users - update for Magento 2.4, for those using official php docker images - I had to use `--with-freetype` rather than @cgalvaojr answer `--with-freetype-dir`, like this:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get update -qq

# apt packages we might need:
RUN apt-get install -y -qq wget git ssh mariadb-client unzip vim rsync nginx jq

# extensions already in: ctype curl hash iconv pic ftp mbstring mysqlnd argon2 sodium pdo_sqlite sqlite3 libedit openssl zlib pear
# official Magento 2.4 required exts: bcmath ctype curl dom gd hash iconv intl mbstring openssl pdo_mysql simplexml soap xsl zip sockets

# for php extensions - not needed, all preinstalled except for gd:
RUN apt-get install -y -qq libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libsodium-dev libzip-dev libfreetype6-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath gd intl pdo_mysql simplexml soap xsl zip sockets
RUN docker-php-ext-enable bcmath gd intl pdo_mysql simplexml soap xsl zip sockets
```

Comment: docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd //need to run this to take effect

Comment: @hkguile - you shouldn't need to. Installation of `gd` is handled in the penultimate line of the provided code, and all `-j$(nproc)` will do is parallelise the job across mutliple cores. It will likely make building the image faster, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: ooo man you saved me upvoted

Answer (score 3):

I found fix for development environment, because I use Mac OS and the apache php doesn't support these fonts and it's a lot of work to get it working and not mess up my system.

open `vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php` and add return in the constructor after the parent is called like this

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param  array|\Traversable $options
 * @throws Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException
 */
public function __construct($options = null)
{
    parent::__construct($options);
    return;

    if (! extension_loaded("gd")) {
        throw new Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException("Image CAPTCHA requires GD extension");
    }

    if (! function_exists("imagepng")) {
        throw new Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException("Image CAPTCHA requires PNG support");
    }

    if (! function_exists("imageftbbox")) {
        throw new Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException("Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an absolutely terrible answer; you should _never_  modify _anything_ in `vendor`.

Comment: After a couple of hours digging only that helped, note that I changed the file only on my machine, the prosuction server was with the oeiginal file.

Comment: Unless it's purely for debugging modifications to check what core code is doing (even then with a decent IDE this shouldn't be necessary); you should_ absolutely_ not be touching anything in `vendor`. You certainly shouldn't recommend others do without adding huge caveats.

If you need to modify code in `vendor` to get something to work then your code is broken and your solution is wrong.

Comment: I don't recommend to do it in production, the first line says "I found fix for development environment", because most of the time the dev environment is different than production. For example I'm developing on Mac, but the production is on Linux, in order to use exactly the same software, versions and configs I need to invest a lot of time to setup some kind of container which I don't want to do.

Comment: Learning how to use Docker for a simple dev env takes about a week. If you're so unwilling to spend that amount of time learning how to use the tools of your trade in order to ensure a consistent development environment between the platforms you work with then I sincerely hope I never have to inherit a codebase you've touched. 

I doubt you even require containers, just a single, simple dependecy installed.

Advising people to do critically stupid things like edit _anything_ in vendor, regardless of whether they're in dev or prod is just fundamentally poor advice.

Comment: @nacholibre thank you for taking the time to answer it helped.

Comment: This is bad advice. I do urge you consider removing this answer.

Comment: this answer helped me to temporarly solve the problem and get the darn thing running, may be this wasn't a good answer but if ft fonts are not available, the system should throw a warning and fallback to available options instead of crashing the whole thing, so my thumbs up to this answer, the problem is in the package not this answer

Answer (score 2):

For me (using docker) solves problem with:

FROM php:7.2.0-fpm-stretch

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing libfreetype6-dev 
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ 
&& docker-php-ext-install gd

Answer (score 1):

This is almost definitely caused by the underlying system not having FreeType installed (if FreeType *is* already installed then @user3338098's solution should fix it).

If you come across this problem *absolutely do not* follow the most upvoted answer (@nacholibre's). Either install the freetype library on your server (usually `freetype`, `libfreetype` or similar, will vary depending on distro. `apt install freetype` should work on Ubuntu), or ask your hosting provider to do so for you. In fact, if you need to ask a managed Magento hosting provider to do this for you then just swap hosting provider.

*Never, ever* modify code in `vendor`. If you need to do so then you are doing something *very, very, *very** wrong; it completely negates the whole point of using Composer in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Magento 2.2 has changed the behaviour of the Magento_Captha module to have both the frontend and the admin captcha enabled by default, compared to earlier 2.x versions where the opposite was true

On machines without FreeType built into the PHP GD library (such as OSX High Sierra) this will give the above error when trying to login to the Magento admin system

'main.CRITICAL: Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support'

A simple resolution for non-production environments is to disable the behaviour as per earlier Magento versions

> vendor/magento/module-captcha/etc/config.xml

```
   <admin>
        <captcha>
            <type>default</type>
            <enable>0</enable>
```

...

```
    <customer>
        <captcha>
            <type>default</type>
            <enable>0</enable>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can alternatively disable the module locally as follows

`bin/magento module:disable Magento_Captcha`

Comment: No you cannot disable the module on a standard installation. You will get something like : `Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints: Cannot disable Magento_Captcha because modules depend on it: Magento_AdminAnalytics...`