# Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support While Logging to Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, captcha, core-config-data

I installed a fresh copy of Magento2 Latest version (2.2.0) on my live site but when i try to login via admin panel it throws the below error

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support Error log record number:
>   1185338139961

I don't know why it is happening can anyone help?

Comment: Please make sure to search a little bit before posting duplicate posts, Because it's certainly against the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding **libfreetype.so** file in **user/lib64** directory (in my case it was ***root/lib64***).

The **libfreetype.so** file should contain the following code

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs --enable-bcmath --with-curl --with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64/ --with-png-dir=/usr/lib64/ --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib64/ \
--enable-intl --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-openssl \
--with-pdo-mysql --enable-soap --with-xsl --enable-zip --enable-opcache
```

**Note**: Don't forget to restart your server after adding the script.

Credits goes to [Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196527/image-captcha-requires-ft-fonts-support)